# How to get catboost visualization to show the categories

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

Consider the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
y_train = pd.DataFrame({0: {14194: 'Fake', 13891: 'Fake', 13247: 'Fake', 11236: 'Fake', 2716: 'Real', 2705: 'Real', 16133: 'Fake', 7652: 'Real', 7725: 'Real', 16183: 'Fake'}})

X_train = pd.DataFrame({'one': {14194: 'e',
  13891: 'b',
  13247: 'v',
  11236: 't',
  2716: 'e',
  2705: 'e',
  16133: 'h',
  7652: 's',
  7725: 's',
  16183: 's'},
 'two': {14194: 'a',
  13891: 'a',
  13247: 'e',
  11236: 'n',
  2716: 'c',
  2705: 'a',
  16133: 'n',
  7652: 'e',
  7725: 'h',
  16183: 'e'},
 'three': {14194: 's',
  13891: 'l',
  13247: 'n',
  11236: 'c',
  2716: 'h',
  2705: 'r',
  16133: 'i',
  7652: 'r',
  7725: 'e',
  16183: 's'},
 'four': {14194: 'd',
  13891: 'e',
  13247: 'r',
  11236: 'g',
  2716: 'o',
  2705: 'r',
  16133: 'p',
  7652: 'v',
  7725: 'r',
  16183: 'i'},
 'five': {14194: 'f',
  13891: 'b',
  13247: 'o',
  11236: 'b',
  2716: 'i',
  2705: 'i',
  16133: 'i',
  7652: 'i',
  7725: 'b',
  16183: 'i'},
 'six': {14194: 'p',
  13891: 's',
  13247: 'l',
  11236: 'l',
  2716: 'n',
  2705: 'n',
  16133: 'n',
  7652: 'l',
  7725: 'e',
  16183: 'u'},
 'seven': {14194: 's',
  13891: 's',
  13247: 's',
  11236: 'e',
  2716: 'g',
  2705: 'g',
  16133: 's',
  7652: 'e',
  7725: 't',
  16183: 'r'}})
```

and the following code:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from catboost import Pool
cat_features = list(X_train.columns)
pool = Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=list(range(7)), feature_names=cat_features)
model = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0).fit(pool)
model.plot_tree(
tree_idx=1,
pool=pool # "pool" is required parameter for trees with one hot features
)
```

I get the following:

[image]

But I don't understand what {five} pr_num0 tb0 type0, value>8 means. I was hoping it would look like the titanic example from the manual which is:

```
import catboost
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool

from catboost.datasets import titanic
titanic_df = titanic()

X = titanic_df[0].drop('Survived',axis=1)
y = titanic_df[0].Survived

is_cat = (X.dtypes != float)
for feature, feat_is_cat in is_cat.to_dict().items():
    if feat_is_cat:
        X[feature].fillna("NAN", inplace=True)

cat_features_index = np.where(is_cat)[0]
pool = Pool(X, y, cat_features=cat_features_index, feature_names=list(X.columns))

model = CatBoostClassifier(
    max_depth=2, verbose=False, max_ctr_complexity=1, iterations=2).fit(pool)

model.plot_tree(
    tree_idx=0,
    pool=pool
)
```

This gives:

[image]

How can I get the equivalent of `Sex, value = Female` for my example? That would be for example, `One, value = b`.

Comment: This looks like an issue with using `repr`. Is there a way of using a custom stringifier function?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I would love to know. Could you give some more details of your thoughts on this? The example I provided is complete so you should be able to run it on your PC and get the same output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR;** This is not really a visualization problem but more on how a feature-split is done in Catboost.

Catboost decides which feature to one-hot and which to ctr based on a parameter called `one_hot_max_size`. If the number of classes in a feature is <= `one_hot_max_size` then it would be treated as a one-hot. By default its set to 2. So only binary features (0,1 or male,female) are considered as one-hot and others (such as PClass -> 1,2,3) are handled as ctr. Setting it high enough will allow you to force catboost to encode your columns as one-hot.

The `{five} pr_num0 tb0 type0, value>8` is basically a label, value for a ctr split. There is no documentation available for this but after inspecting the github repo, it seems the label is generated using a multi-hash.

More details below.

---

#### How are feature-splits selected?

A `feature-split` pair is chosen for a leaf in 3 steps:

1. A list is formed of possible candidates (“feature-split pairs”) to be assigned to a leaf as the split.
2. A number of penalty functions are calculated for each object (on the condition that all of the candidates obtained from step 1 have been assigned to the leaf).
3. The split with the smallest penalty is selected.

#### Types of feature-splits

There are three types of splits: `FloatFeature`, `OneHotFeature` and `OnlineCtr`. These are based on the encoding that is done on the features.

1. **FloatFeature:** A float feature split takes a float type feature and split value is calculated (border). A float feature is represented in the visualization as with a feature index and border value ([check this](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/visualize_decision_trees_tutorial.ipynb)):

```
9, border<257.23    #feature index, border value
```

2. **OneHotFeature**: In a one-hot feature, each class can be represented by a `max of n possible values (0 or 1)`. The `n` is decided by a parameter called `one_hot_max_size` which is set to 2 by default.  Note in the titanic dataset case, `Sex` has only 2 possible values, `Male` or `Female`. If you set `one_hot_max_size=4` then catboost uses one hot to encode features with upto 4 unique classes (e.g. Pclass in titanic has 3 unique classes). A one-hot feature is represented with the feature name, and its value:

```
Sex, value=Female    #feature name, value
```

3. **OnlineCtr**: A ctr the third type of split that you can see in a catboost model. Ctrs are not calculated for features that are used with one-hot encoding ([link](https://catboost.ai/docs/features/categorical-features.html)). If the number of possible classes in a feature exceeds the limit set by `one_hot_max_size` then catboost automatically uses ctr to encode features and thus type of split is an OnlineCtr. Its represented with the feature name, some dummy tokens that represent unique classes and a value:

```
{five} pr_num1 tb0 type0, value>9  #Label, value

##Inspecting github, the label seems to be from a multihash
##The multihash seems to be made from (CatFeatureIdx, CtrIdx, TargetBorderIdx, PriorIdx)
##https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/libs/data/ctrs.h
```

#### Analyzing the dataset at hand

Let's first look at the number of unique classes in each of the features.

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool
import pandas as pd

X_train.describe().loc['unique']
```

```
one      6
two      5
three    8
four     8
five     4
six      6
seven    5
Name: unique, dtype: object
```

As you can see, the minimum number of unique classes is 4 (in feature called "five") and the maximum is 8. Lets set our `one_hot_max_size = 4`.

```
cat_features = list(X_train.columns)
pool = Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=list(range(7)), feature_names=cat_features)
model = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0, one_hot_max_size=4).fit(pool)

model.plot_tree(tree_idx=1,pool=pool)
```

[image]

The feature "five" is now `OneHotFeature` and results in a split description of `five, value=i`. However, feature "One" is still a `OnlineCtr`.

Lets now set the `one_hot_max_size = 8`, which is the max possible unique classes. This would ensure that each of the features is `OneHotFeature` and not `OnlineCtr`

```
cat_features = list(X_train.columns)
pool = Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=list(range(7)), feature_names=cat_features)
model = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0, one_hot_max_size=8).fit(pool)

model.plot_tree(tree_idx=1,pool=pool)
```

[image]

---

Hope this clarifies your question about why `Sex` from titanic is being displayed in a different manner as compared to the features that you are working with.

For more reading on this check these links -

1. https://colab.research.google.com/github/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/model_export_as_json_tutorial.ipynb
2. https://catboost.ai/docs/features/categorical-features.html
3. https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic.html#algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic
4. https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/visualize_decision_trees_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.  I am still frustrated that for a large dataset, if you do set one_hot_max_size to be large than you get a worse classifier even though it is now interpretable. This seems to be because it can't make "feature combinations" any more.

Comment: I would recommend keeping features with smaller cardinality as one-hot and letting the larger cardinality features be split as ctr.